# Namespace found in Object browser but missing from the reference library

Tags: .net, vb.net, reference

I was importing a old project and got a bunch of errors while building. Most errors were similar, saying 'type or namespace does not exist in the namespace etc'

I took one particular error which was about a missing namespace 'System.Windows.Forms.Design.Behavior'. 
I could see this namespace in Object browser:

[image: object browser]

But not in the Add Reference window:

[image]

I could not find any files with that name under this folder too.

```
G:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\
```

This namespace exists in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.DESIGN.BEHAVIOR%29;k%28BEHAVIOR%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true).

How do I use this namespace in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't find a file with exactly that name because it is not mandatory for a namespace to have the same name of the assembly containing it.
The one you refer it is probably defined in `System.Design.dll`

Comment: Also, a namespace may span several different assemblies.